# Help with newenvironment for unnumbered theorems

Tags: macros, environments, newtheorem

First I tried this `\newenvironment{axioma}[2]{\newtheorem*{#1}{#2} \begin{#1}}{\end{#1}}`. It did not work.

Then I tried `\newenvironment{axioma}[1]{\newcommand{\axiomhead}{\newtheorem*{kkk}{#1}} \axiomhead \begin{kkk}}{\end{kkk}}`

It works only once. When I use a second call, it says that `kkk is already defined`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Define the label to be variable. You just need one theorem environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\axiomname}{}
\newtheorem*{axiominner}{\axiomname}
\newenvironment{axioma}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\axiomname}{#1}\axiominner}
 {\endaxiominner}

\begin{document}

\begin{axioma}{Extensionality}
$A=B$ if and only if ...
\end{axioma}

\begin{axioma}{Choice}
This is complicated.
\end{axioma}

\end{document}
```

[image]